# Integral of f(x)

Tags: calculus

Given that $f(x)=\dfrac{x^3+3}{\sqrt{x^4+4x+4}}$.
How do I integrate the function.
I tried by changing variables but am getting stack as $4x^3+4$ can not divide $x^3+3.$
Thank you in advance.

Comment: $\mathbf{Hint:}\dfrac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{x^4+4x+4})=\dfrac{4x^3+4}{2\sqrt{x^4+4x+4}}= \dfrac{2x^3+2}{\sqrt{x^4+4x+4}}$

Comment: @user83845, may I know the source as  http://goo.gl/chFtrc